# Intercepting session time-out when calling show on rich:modalpanel

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am trying to intercept a session time-out when a user click on commadLink that shows a modal panel. So far, I haven't been successful...

Example : 
`<a4j:commandLink execute="@form" oncomplete="#{rich:component('ContactModalPanel')}.show(); return false;"  limitRender="true"  render=":ContactModalPanelSubViewForm:ContactDataTable">`

Many thanks,

JSF 2.1
RichFaces 4.3.3.Final

Comment: Is it really important to react on session time out when user click link for show modal panel? When user click to other UI element which used for redirection (menu, buttons, links, ...), then he will be redirected to some special page used for this purpose.

Comment: Hi Vasil. Yes it is important, because the modal shows, it gives the user the impression the session is still valid. I have implemented a Filter but it doesn't get hit by the modal.

Comment: Show modal window is client side action. Filter can't help in this case.

Comment: If you are not going to implement some kind of complex refreshable counter by javascript to determine session timeout then there is no other way than do ajax request to server before displaying the modal. So, if ajax returns with error then you can do alert or navigate out from current page.
Another note: you're using ajax command link (which produces javascript code) for nothing (always return false), simple <a> may be used.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Nigi. I wanted to avoid to write some javascript, I think I won't have any other choice.